# Buy all items of a shopping list from minimum number of shops

Tags: algorithm

I have a list of n items that I want to buy. (Each item is distinct)

```
list = {item1, item2, item3 .... itemn}
```

I know k shops and list of items available on these shops.

```
shop1 = {item3, item5, item6 ...}
shop2 = {item1, item5, item8 ...}
...
shopk = {item1, item6, item8 ...}
```

It is guaranteed that each item on my list is available on at least 1 of the k shops.
Once you visit a shop, you can buy 1 or more number of items of your choice.

**Question** I want to minimize the number of shops I need to visit to buy all items on my list.

**My Solution1** I used Brute force DFS with memoization. This gives optimal solution but has expensive complexity(O(n!)) and not feasible for my requirement. (k and n can reach up to 300 sometimes)

**My Solution2** I used a greedy solution in which I visit the shop that offers maximum number of items on my list. Buy items, and remove all those items from list. I repeat this unless my shopping list is not empty. (All required items are not bought)

Although solution 2 runs very fast Unfortunately this solution is not optimal.

**Working on Solution3** While googling, I found a similar problem that was solved using bipartite graph and flow. (I am still trying to set an analogy and check applicability of this approach for my problem)

Is this a known problem? If no, Is it possible to modify solution 2 to get optimal solution?

I would thankful if you can help me solving this problem by suggesting some code snippet in any language or any approach or keyword(algorithm name) etc

Comment: You can try [formulating the problem as](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Integer_linear_program_formulation) an [integer program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) and use a general ILP solver to solve it. Unless the instances are really hard, you might get good results with that. As dasblinkenlight mentioned, there's probably no polynomial time solution.

Comment: @NiklasB. Thank you, ILP formulation suggested by you sounds promising. I will try this and update result if it is practical for my size bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a known problem?

Yes, this is a [Set Cover Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) (specifically, its unweighted variety). It is known to be NP-complete, so you are currently limited to solutions that are either approximate or too slow to be practical.

Comment: Thank you. Set Cover Problem is the word I wanted.